# Getting Null When Second List Item's Buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've written a leaflet library along with some udemy teacher. After the project finished I decided to add some features to it. The problem is only the second object's buttons in the list which are 'close' and 'edit' does not clickable but the others are working fine. Even worse I get **null** when I click on them. And only after I can close the second when the first from the below object is closed. I also store the list objects to the `#workouts` array.

[image: I drew a circle to the not clickable list object.].

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const edit = document.querySelector('.form.form_edit');
const containerWorkouts = document.querySelector('.workouts');
const inputType = document.querySelector('.form__input--type');
const inputDistance = document.querySelector('.form__input--distance');
const inputDuration = document.querySelector('.form__input--duration');
const inputCadence = document.querySelector('.form__input--cadence');
const inputElevation = document.querySelector('.form__input--elevation');
```

Above i pasted the query selectors.

```
class App{
    #map;
    #mapZoomLevel = 13;
    #mapEvent;
    #workouts = [];

    constructor(){
        
        this._getPosition();

        this._getLocalStorage();
        
        
        form.addEventListener("submit", this._newWorkout.bind(this));
        
        inputType.addEventListener("change", this._toggleElevationField.bind(this));
        containerWorkouts.addEventListener("click", this._moveToPopup.bind(this));   
        containerWorkouts.addEventListener("click", this._deleteWorkout.bind(this));
        
        
    }
```

and this is the where I use the query selectors. They are in the constructor of the **App Class**.`_moveToPopup` function works fine however the feature that I created which is `_deleteWorkout` does not work properly. When the second object's in the list close button is clicked I get **null** from the `workoutEl` variable that belongs in the `_deleteWorkout` function.

```
_deleteWorkout(e){
        const workoutEl = e.target.closest(".x");
        console.log(workoutEl);
        
        if (!workoutEl) return;

        workoutEl.parentElement.remove();
    }
```

I get **null** from this `console.log(workoutEl);` when second object's close button is clicked.

The problem is why only the second object's buttons of the list item are not clickable, so weird.

Here is the relevant HTML code which are showing the list which is in the screenshot.

```
let html = `
    <li  class="contianer workout workout--${workout.type}" data-id="${workout.id  }">
    <button class="x">x</button>
    <button class="edit">edit</button>
      <h2 class="workout__title">${workout.description}</h2>
      <div class="workout__details">
        <span class="workout__icon">${workout.type === "running" ? "‍♂️": ""}</span>
        <span class="workout__value">${workout.distance}</span>
        <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
      </div>
      <div class="workout__details">
        <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
        <span class="workout__value">${workout.duration}</span>
        <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
      </div>`;

    if (workout.type === "running"){
        html += `
        <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${workout.pace.toFixed(1)}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">min/km</span>
      </div>
      <div class="workout__details">
        <span class="workout__icon"></span>
        <span class="workout__value">${workout.cadence}</span>
        <span class="workout__unit">spm</span>
      </div>
    </li>`
    }
```

Comment: Is it only for the second card? Are you able to click the 'x' button on third and first card?

Comment: Yes only for the Second. And when the first, bottom, element 'x' clicked, closed and disappeared after that i can close the second.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I handle delete function was like this:

```
  _deleteWorkout(e) {
      const workoutEl = e.target.closest(".workout");
      const workoutItem = this.#workOuts.find(
      (work) => work.id === workoutEl.dataset.id );
      const index = this.#workOuts.indexOf(workoutItem);
      // remove from workout list
      e.target.closest(".workout").classList.add("delete");
     // delete from workOuts array (local storage)
     this.#workOuts.splice(index, 1);
     this._setLocalStorage();
}
```

#workOuts is an array which holds all workout which is created from _newWorkout() function
also you can add a "delete" class to workout class in your CSS and set display to none for removing your workout